# Android - Trigger OnClickListener on LinearLayout even through an ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an horizontal LinearLayout within which there is a small ImageButton. The LinearLayout has its `clickable` property set to `true`, and so does the ImageButton.

From within code, I look for the LinearLayout and set an onClickListener event to it. Everything works fine, but I was expecting it to work if a touch occurs on the ImageButton too.

*One possible workaround* would be to attach an onClickListener event to the ImageButton, but I thought there might be some sort of property to let touches "pass through" the ImageButton and let the LinearLayout manage the event.

Thanks

---

### Solution

Thomas' suggestion worked perfectly. If you are experiencing this same issue, consider setting your LinearLayout's `descendantFocusability` to `beforeDescendants`.

Comment: Try using the descendantFocusablity property on your linearlayout. Set beforeDescendants as value.

Comment: Settting `clickable` tot `true` for the `ImageButton`, makes it to seal any click events within its bounds. Maybe you need exactly the opposite.

Comment: Hey Thomas, that was the right answer. I was looking for that property (or some other of the like) in the editor GUI. Still don't know why it doesn't appear in the "Properties tab". Anyway, consider writing your workaround as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Hey ana, I tried it but didn't work either. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Add this to your `ImageButton`

Comment: That was my original configuration and doesn't work either, Adeel. The right anwers was Thomas', i.e. setting LinearLayout's `descendantFocusability` to `beforeDescendants`. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Any focus on element set to focusable & clickable to false such as

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

If it is not working then use the **ImageView instead of ImageButton.**